Calculating confidence interval while fitting multiple datasets simultaneously.
I am dealing with six experimental datasets of two species interaction and I want to fit these six datasets to a coupled ode system simultaneously to get a set of estimated parameters and corresponding C.I.
While I am trying to do above I am not able to fit them altogether.
Can any one tell which package I can use in R to do so.

What is your previous experience? For instance, could you solve or translate my solution to the task in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71722061/trying-to-infer-model-parameter-of-lotka-volterra-model to R with some fitting or regression module?
